# How to test whether SMTP connection credentials are correct without sending email in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I have configured the PHP mailer settings in WordPress in the following way. How can I verify if the STMP credentials that I set are correct or not without sending any email using `wp_mail()`?

```
add_action('phpmailer_init', 'wpse8170_phpmailer_init');

function wpse8170_phpmailer_init(PHPMailer $phpmailer)
{
    $phpmailer->Host = 'your.smtp.server.here';
    $phpmailer->Port = 25; // could be different
    $phpmailer->Username = 'your_username@example.com'; // if required
    $phpmailer->Password = 'yourpassword'; // if required
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // if required
    // $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    // enable if required, 'tls' is another possible value

    $phpmailer->IsSMTP();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SmtpConnect method of PHPMailer, and if the connection fails you can dump it to the WordPress error log.

```
try {
    $connection = $phpmailer->SmtpConnect();
} catch(Exception $error) {
    echo "PHPMailer Failed to connect : " . $error;
}
```